# Apply Css for the element based on content placed location using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the html content, I need to apply css based on the location placed in the content.

Example: I have two page, but same js file loading for both pages. I need to apply the css for only one page based on content placed location.

I need to apply the css(generic css) for test content only for page2.(id=test have after the main tag).

Use only javascript not jQuery.

```js
//I need to apply the css for test content only for page2.(id=test have after the main tag).

var contentArea = document.querySelector('.wp-body:not(main >:not(.sample-page)) #test');
    if(contentArea){
      contentArea.style.color = 'red'; //color is dynamic data
    }
```

```html
Page1:
<body class="wp-body">
  <main >
      <div class="sample-page"></div>
      <div id="test">
        <span> ABCD</span>
        <span> EFGH</span>
      </div>
  </main>
</body>

Page2: 
<body class="wp-body">
  <main >
      <div>xxx</div>
  </main>
  <div id="test">
    <span> ABCD</span>
    <span> EFGH</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why the heck would you do this using JS? Write proper CSS selectors instead.

Comment: I am working existing html page. I can able to add only js code.

Comment: Could you load different .js or .css file in your html then ?

Comment: No, both files load same js and css files.

Comment: Select `#test`, and do something with it or not based on a simple check whether its parent is the body element or not ...

Comment: @CBroe - sorry i didn;t get.

Comment: The first #test is in a main div, not the second one. Is this an error ? Otherwise you could go with document.querySelector('main > #test') to get only the first test div

Answer (score 0):

you need to add class to the body tag and then write separate css rules for the children of body.page2 or body.page1

```
.wp-body main #test {} //points only to the #test div on page1
.wp-body > #test {} //points only to the #test div on page2

$(".wp-body main #test").css()  //set the style for #test div on page 1
$(".wp-body > #test").css() // set the style for #test div on page 2
```

Comment: I need to add the style using java-script. because it's dynamic value

Comment: please check my html,  .sample-page div closed before #test content. Also only javascript. not jquery

Comment: as you changed your html I have changed my selectors. There is still different structure, so you can target it by css selectors (also by jquery selectors)

Comment: I think it's good idea, don't know why i didn't think simple like your approach. thanks